# vim: cannot click past col 90

Tags: vim, mouse

Since I'm pretty new with vim, I (still) find the mouse very useful to click somewhere (to move quickly) and select blocks of text.

in my vimrc:
`set mouse=a`

and also
`set textwidth=80`
`set colorcolumn=80`

I can click to move the cursor, **but not after the column 91**. I really don't understand why this behaviour and why this arbitrary limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limiting the effective width of your document to 80 columns. No wonder clicking outside of this arbitrary limit - that you choose - does nothing.

To be able to click anywhere, you must

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

but it doesn't make much sense if you set hard physical limits to your content.

Comment: But it apparently still works in columns 80-90?! This rather reminds me of this recently fixed bug: _7.3.632  cannot select beyond 222 columns with the mouse in xterm_

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set fileencoding and encoding of vim be the same value,

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

and make sure your locale is the same value, too.

you can use 'locale' command to get your own locale in a terminal.