# cannot click to move the cursor after the column 91 in vim in windows terminal

Tags: vim, windows-terminal

In windows terminal, I can click to move the cursor, but can not click after the column 91 by mouse in vim.
but I can click to move the curor after th column 91 in others terminal, such as MobaXterm.
I also have tried the solution from [vim: cannot click past col 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438166/vim-cannot-click-past-col-90), but it is not workable for me.

I just set `set mouse=a` in my .vimrc.
I cannot find setting in windows terminal to fix this arbitrary limit.

Comment: Just to make sure, what do you get when in Vim you type `:set textwidth` ?  If it is anything other than "0", try `:set tw=0` and see if that lets you click past column 91.  (If that works, then consider putting `set textwidth=0` in your .vimrc file.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that due to some limitations Windows Terminal can only handle mouse support in vim for up to 93 columns with `xterm` set for `ttymouse`. This is discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5454#issuecomment-656250431).

The good thing is that in this thread there is also a solution provided: Change the value of `ttymouse` to `sgr`. So just type `:set ttymouse=sgr` or even better add `set ttymouse=sgr` into your `.vmirc`.